# Using SFML and Qt

Tags: c++, qt, sfml

I use SFML in console mode, because I want to make a level editor, and the GUI would take forever to code, should I merge SFML with Qt? so I can use Qt to make levels, then when I make the actual game engine ( A separate project that just loads the map files made in the map editor ) I won't use Qt anymore?

So should I use Qt or just a basic Win32 GUI project to merge with SFML to make a map editor, and how would i do it exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SFML and Qt both have opengl capabilities so this would definately be an option. I'd recommend it aswell since with Qt you can customise the style sheets to make it more suitable to the game environment.

Comment: Thank you, coding GUI for a program would take a very long time and take up lots of room, so this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a great combination to make level editors or other game tools. In [my blog](http://becomingindiedev.blogspot.com.es/2013/10/qt-5-and-sfml-20-integration.html), I posted how to perform the integration for Mac OS and SFML 2.0. And some early achievements on making a 2D level editor using this integration is shown [here](http://becomingindiedev.blogspot.com.es/2013/10/first-experiments-with-qt-and-sfml.html).